# How to sum values from three unrelated tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sum values from two unrelated tables but the third table has just the state names which need to be join to the other two tables so I can have a full list of states. Here is my code

```
    SELECT COALESCE(c.StateName, k.StateName, s.Name) as StateName,
       (COALESCE(c.[Age 17 or Younger],0)+COALESCE( k.[Age 17 or Younger],0)) as [Age 17 or Younger]
FROM NamrsFullDw.UsState 
     Left Join 
      (SELECT StateName, SUM(PerpAge17) AS [Age 17 or Younger] 
      FROM NamrsFrozen2017.CaseKeyIndicator2017
      WHERE FiscalYear = 2017
      GROUP BY StateName
     ) c FULL Outer JOIN
     (SELECT StateName, SUM(PerpAge17) AS [Age 17 or Younger]
      FROM NamrsFrozen2017.KeyIndicator2017
      WHERE FiscalYear = 2017
      GROUP BY StateName
     ) k 
     on c.StateName=k.StateName;
```

Comment: You need to provide some kind of detail. It is not at all clear what you want to do. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for ideas of how to ask. You also need to provide some data, table definitions and desired output. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some ideas on what info you should post. The code you posted is lacking formatting so it really difficult to read. But you have no join predicates on c.

Comment: Please share some sample data with us. The code by itself is not enough.

Comment: I cant provide data its confidential @SQL_M

Comment: I cant provide data its confidential @SeanLange

Comment: It should never be real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your COALESCE over the state Name is not necessary, as you have a catalog table that contains all the names you need and you are joining by this field, S (BTW you are using the alias in your select but you are not aliasing any table in your from with that name).

You also are missing the ON clause on your first join

A full join is not necessary as a left join to your catalog table covers what you need

COALESCE is SQL ISO Standard but as you are comparing only two values and you are using SQL Server, ISNULL is better to perform that operation

Use two left joins

```
SELECT 
    s.Name as StateName,
    (ISNULL(c.[Age 17 or Younger],0) + ISNULL( k.[Age 17 or Younger],0)) as [Age 17 or Younger]
FROM NamrsFullDw.UsState S
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT StateName, SUM(PerpAge17) AS [Age 17 or Younger] 
    FROM NamrsFrozen2017.CaseKeyIndicator2017
    WHERE FiscalYear = 2017
    GROUP BY StateName
) c on c.StateName = S.StateName
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT StateName, SUM(PerpAge17) AS [Age 17 or Younger]
    FROM NamrsFrozen2017.KeyIndicator2017
    WHERE FiscalYear = 2017
    GROUP BY StateName
) k on k.StateName = s.Name;
```

Or you can use union all

```
SELECT 
    s.Name as StateName,
    ISNULL(SUM(k.[Age 17 or Younger]),0) as [Age 17 or Younger]
FROM NamrsFullDw.UsState S
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT StateName, SUM(PerpAge17) AS [Age 17 or Younger] 
    FROM NamrsFrozen2017.CaseKeyIndicator2017
    WHERE FiscalYear = 2017
    GROUP BY StateName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT StateName, SUM(PerpAge17) AS [Age 17 or Younger]
    FROM NamrsFrozen2017.KeyIndicator2017
    WHERE FiscalYear = 2017
    GROUP BY StateName
) k on c.StateName = s.Name
GROUP BY s.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this... some sample data does help...

```
drop table #states;
drop table #case_key_indicator;
drop table #key_indicator;

create table #states (StateName char(2));
create table #case_key_indicator (StateName char(2), FiscalYear int, PerpAge17 int);
create table #key_indicator (StateName char(2), FiscalYear int, PerpAge17 int);

insert into #states values ('CA'), ('IA'), ('TX'), ('OR'), ('OH'), ('WI'), ('RI');
insert into #case_key_indicator values ('CA', 2017, 5), ('IA', 2017, 3), ('TX', 2017, 1), ('TX', 2018, 7), ('TX', 2019, 3);
insert into #key_indicator values ('CA', 2017, 5), ('IA', 2019, 3), ('OR', 2017, 1), ('WI', 2018, 1), ('RI', 2017, 1), ('TX', 2017, 2);

with
frozen2017 as
(
select case when c.StateName is null then k.StateName else c.StateName end as StateName
      ,case when c.FiscalYear is null then k.FiscalYear else c.FiscalYear end as FiscalYear
      ,SUM(c.PerpAge17) as sum_c
      ,SUM(k.PerpAge17) as sum_k
      ,isnull(SUM(c.PerpAge17), 0)  + isnull(SUM(k.PerpAge17), 0) AS [Age 17 or Younger]
  from #case_key_indicator c
       full outer join
       #key_indicator k
          on c.StateName = k.StateName
             and c.FiscalYear = k.FiscalYear
 where case when c.FiscalYear is null then k.FiscalYear else c.FiscalYear end = 2017
group by case when c.StateName is null then k.StateName else c.StateName end
        ,case when c.FiscalYear is null then k.FiscalYear else c.FiscalYear end
)
SELECT s.StateName
      ,isnull(z.[Age 17 or Younger], 0) as [Age 17 or Younger]
,*
  FROM #states s
       left outer join
       frozen2017 z
          on s.StateName = z.StateName
order by s.StateName
```